# Getting .eq to ignor NAN values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, ipython

I have a data frame (df) that looks like

```
PID     SID     RID     
124     294     294
954     299     299
NAN     949     493
959     NAN     959
059     059     059 
0405    NAN     NAN
493     942     395
```

I used

```
testdf = df.eq(df["PID"], axis='index').all(axis=1)
```

to get a list (testdf) that reports if the values across roles are equal, this works except that the NAN get in the way.

I tried to use

```
testdf = df.eq(df["PID"], axis='index').all(axis=1).notnull()
```

but for some reason it reports everything as equal when i know some rows aren't.

Here is an example of what I would want testdf to look like in the end

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    True
4    True
5    False
6    False
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear for me. You want to compare two `DataFrame` (`df` and `df2) with similar data ?

Comment: Updated it now, hopefully its more clear.

Comment: I don't understand why do you think the output is incorrect?

Comment: Ok, if I understand you want to get `PID` with `SID==RID` and `SID!=RID`. Is that correct ?

Comment: EdChum, when i use

    testdf = df.eq(df["PID"], axis='index').all(axis=1).notnull()

testdef reports everything as true, when I know some values across the rows are not equal.

Comment: `testdf = df.eq(df["PID"], axis='index').all(axis=1).notnull()` produces all `True` because the result of the inner Series is a boolean Series, so they clearly are not `NaN` values

Comment: Romain,  I am sorry I do not understand your statement I am new to programming. I want to check if PID = SID = RID for every row, ignoring NAN values.

Comment: The inner test: `In [3]:

df.eq(df["PID"], axis='index').all(axis=1)
Out[3]:
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
dtype: bool` is correct only index row 4 is `True` because all rows are equal, so what's wrong this?

Comment: thanks edchum I understand now why it isn't working. the reason its wrong for me is because index row 3 is     false when I want it to report true by ignoring the NAN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `NaN` can be ignored we can fill `NaN` in each column (`RID` and `SID`) with each other values. If the remaining values are equal to the `PID` the result will be `True` else it will be `False`.
You can do it on a copy of the `DataFrame` in order to not alter your original data.

```
df['SID'] = df['SID'].fillna(df['RID'])
df['RID'] = df['RID'].fillna(df['SID'])
testdf = df.eq(df['PID'], axis='index').all(axis=1)
testdf
```

Here is the result:

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False
```

Comment: this would work if i was just comparing SID to RID but I want test across each row (index) if the values in SID PID and RID are the same but I want it to ignore NAN.  so if index 3 would be true.

Comment: Updated original post with an example of the output I am looking for

Comment: It is more clear now. I have modified my answer, tell me if it can solve your problem.

Comment: Cool even it was difficult for me to understand, sorry.

Comment: Do not forget to check the answer to close the question if it works.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is caused by the fact that `np.nan == np.nan` is `False` and `np.nan != np.nan` is `True`. A quick workaround would be to replace any `nan` in `df` and `df2` with something that you know is not in your dataframes eg `foo`:

```
df = df.fillna("foo")
df2 = df2.fillna("foo")
```

You can then compare your dataframes as you wish.

Comment: If I fill with foo wouldn't I still get a false when comparing across rows?